# How can I specify that an area of my custom WordPress theme have to contains widgets\modules?

Tags: php, content-management-system, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am pretty new in WordPress theme development and I am developing a theme that use BootStra CSS framework

I have to do that a specific area of my theme can contains some widget\module (I don't know what is the correct name in WP, I am refering to the tool setted by backend that show some components output as a gallery immage or a slideshow)

Someone can help me to understand this argument? from what can I start to do this operation?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to wordpress :)

So first thing is to register widget area. In you `functions.php` place the following code:

```
$args = array(
'name'          => __( 'Sidebar name', 'theme_text_domain' ), // name that will show up in the admin
'id'            => 'unique-sidebar-id',
'description'   => '',
    'class'         => '',
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget'  => '</li>',
'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
'after_title'   => '</h2>' );

register_sidebar( $args );
```

For the reference see official [codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar)

Next, call `dynamic_sidebar()` function where you want the content to show up on the site, usually `sidebar.php`

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'unique-sidebar-id' ) ) : ?> //display widget area only if there are widgets asigned in the admin
<ul id="sidebar">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'unique-sidebar-id' ); ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I hope this will get you started.

Comment: my last doubt is related to the 'theme_text_domain' parameter, in my previuos version I passed only the name of the sidebar, what is the difference passing also the name of the theme?

Comment: 'theme_text_domain' parameter is used for translation purposes. every theme should have unique text domain which should be passed after translatable strings. translatable strings are passed inside __('String that should be translatable', 'theme_text_domain'), and text domain should be defined with load_textdomain() function, more here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_textdomain
in other words, if you are not building theme that should support translations, you can just pass simple string for 'name'

Comment: translation is related to multilanguage website?

Comment: yes, strings translations in multilanguage websites